# Use Axios .then() with for loop index variable

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to iterate some page URLs, stored in an array, and retrieve them to do an operation over their html file. Since I need to store a result from said operation for each page to use them the next time I call the function, I want to pass the index (i) in the onResponse call so that it can assign the result to its proper place in the array. But instead of using the i value from the respective i-th iteration, this function call uses pages.length (i's last value). I know why this happens, but I don't know what would be a good solution. Any help here?

```
async function checkPages(){
const dateObj = new Date();
console.log(pages.length)
console.log(`Time: ${dateObj.toTimeString()}\n`);
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
    axios.get(pages[i], { httpsAgent })
      .then(response => onResponse(response, i)
    )
      .catch(function (error) {
        onError(error)
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `let` instead of `var`

```js
for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
```

`let` are block scoped and `var` are function scoped.

Since you are calling an `async` method, using `var` it will finish the `for` loop and pass the last value to the callback. But using `let` it will keep the variable assigned in the block scope in the callback.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is the definition for `let`, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is for `var`.

Comment: Thank you! Not familiar with weakly typed languages at all, so it flew over my head.

Answer (score 1):

`axios.get` is a promise so your foreach is kicking off all http requests and `i` gets to the array length before you get any response from your API.

Try:

```
async function checkPages() {
  const results = await Promise.all(
    pages.map((page) =>
      axios.get(page, { httpsAgent }).catch((error) => {
        onError(error);
      })
    )
  );
  results.forEach((response, i) => {
    onResponse(response, i);
  });
}
```

Comment: code updated, try again

Comment: It's a refactor of his code, which optimizes the requests by paralelizing them. In the answer I gave him I only fixed his issues and offered some knowledge of variable scoping. I like this one.

Comment: requests were already running in parallel in the author's question

Comment: true, my bad, I thought  he had `await` there since he put `async` for the function but he didn't.. Still, your solution is more elegant since you have the order in the results array the same as in the pages array (whereas his solution will resolve in a different order each time)